# sql query returning multiple dates, only need latest date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a query that returns users by first name, last name, user id and a date they've completed an event.

I want the query to only return one row per user, but some users have completed the same event on multiple dates.  I can't use a distinct becuase the dates are distinct, and I can't use a group by for the same reason.

how can I have the query return only the latest date on which the event was completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `group by` , and do a `MAX` on the date field

Something like...

```
Select firstname, lastname, userid, max(datecompleted) 
from events
group by firstname, lastname, userid
```

depending on your data structure.